# jQuery Sortable - attach div

Tags: jquery, html, button, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have an accordion setup as follows:-

```
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; 
}

div.accordion_panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    display: none;
}

div.accordion_panel.show {
    background: #d7d7d7 !important;
    display: block;
}
```

and the html implementation of it as follows:-

```
<ul id="WorkHistoryContainer" class="WorkHistoryContainer">
    <button class="accordion">Work Experience</button>
    <div class="accordion_panel">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p class='form_label'>Employer Name: <input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" name="Employer[]"></p></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p class='form_label'>Position: <input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" name="Position[]"></p></div>   
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Work Experience</button>
    <div class="accordion_panel">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p class='form_label'>Employer Name: <input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" name="Employer[]"></p></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p class='form_label'>Position: <input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" name="Position[]"></p></div>   
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Work Experience</button>
    <div class="accordion_panel">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p class='form_label'>Employer Name: <input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" name="Employer[]"></p></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p class='form_label'>Position: <input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" name="Position[]"></p></div>   
    </div>
</ul>
```

I've basically been trying to make a sortable collapsible accordion, but as I am using bootstrap the accordion built into jQuery UI does not work.

What I am essentially trying to do is make the heading button "Work Experience" sortable, but the underlying div that is shown when its click also needs to be sorted with it. I've tried wrapping the button and div in an LI but then when the button is clicked, the LI expands to cover the viewable contents of the div (as it should). I want to confine the sort to the button, but have the button and the div move with the sort. How can I do this?